# What is the chemical reaction between caustic soda + salt + magnet wire?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

#### Intro

[image: Magnet Wire and Insulation]

Magnet wire(or enameled copper wire) is round insulated Copper wire.
The insulation is generally made of polymer film and this insulating films generally use **polyvinyl formal(Formvar)**, **polyurethane**, **polyamide**...

#### Questions

I'm trying to find the easiest way to strip magnet wire (get the insulation off of magnet wire). I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbHFtX_KtbE) video but I want to know that:

1. What is the chemical equation of this reaction?

$\ce{NaOH + NaCl + Cu + Formvar -> ?}$

As you can see on the video, a gas is coming out.

2. What is the this gas? **Is it dangerous?**
3. **Is copper affected by this reaction?**